# SELECT Data with logic created date not greater than

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have three tables with detail structure and data like this :

1. Table TBL_REFERRAL

   ```
   ID     CREATED_DATE           USER_NAME    REFERRAL_CODE
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   1      28-08-2020 12:15:40    DINA         EM0001
   2      28-08-2020 12:19:42    DINA         EM0002
   3      28-08-2020 12:19:22    LISA         EM0003
   4      28-08-2020 20:00:09    LISA         EM0004
   5      29-08-2020 12:00:05    RYAN         EM0004
   ```
2. Table TBL_USER

   ```
   ID     USER_NAME       UNIQUE_CODE
   ----------------------------------
   1      DINA            UNI0001
   3      LISA            UNI0002
   5      RYAN            UNI0003
   ```
3. Table TBL_CHECKOUT

   ```
   TRANS_ID      UNIQUE_CODE     CREATED_DATE           ITEM         TOTAL
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1112          UNI0001         28-08-2020 12:20:40    Milk          5000
   1113          UNI0002         28-08-2020 12:22:22    Shampoo      12000
   1114          UNI0002         28-08-2020 20:11:09    Biscuit       5000
   1115          UNI0003         29-08-2020 12:02:05    Soap          2000
   ```

Because of some conditions, in the process I can't connect between checkout table and referral. But I want to have a view table that connecting the checkout with referral but I am map that with logic based on created date time between referral and check out. Is it possible to me have the view table like this ? :

```
  REFERRAL_CODE  TRANS_ID  USER_NAME  UNIQUE_CODE  REFERRAL_DATE        CHECKOUT_DATE
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  EM0002         1112      DINA       UNI0001      28-08-2020 12:19:42  28-08-2020 12:20:40
  EM0003         1113      LISA       UNI0002      28-08-2020 12:19:22  28-08-2020 12:22:22
  EM0004         1114      LISA       UNI0002      28-08-2020 20:00:09  28-08-2020 20:11:09 
  EM0004         1115      RYAN       UNI0003      29-08-2020 12:00:05  29-08-2020 12:02:05
```

Updated -> I have been try the query like this  :

```
SELECT 
    a.REFERRAL_CODE, a.USER_NAME, b.UNIQUE_CODE, c.TRANS_ID, 
    a.CREATED_DATE AS "REFERRAL_DATE", c.CREATED_DATE AS "CHECKOUT_DATE"
FROM
    TBL_CHECKOUT c
LEFT JOIN TBL_USER b
 ON c.UNIQUE_CODE = b.UNIQUE_CODE
LEFT JOIN TBL_REFERRAL a
 ON a.USER_NAME = b.USER_NAME
WHERE 
    c.CREATED_DATE > a.CREATED_DATE;
```

The result come is :

```
REFERRAL_CODE  TRANS_ID  USER_NAME  UNIQUE_CODE  REFERRAL_DATE        CHECKOUT_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  EM0001         1112      DINA       UNI0001      28-08-2020 12:15:40  28-08-2020 12:20:40
  EM0002         1112      DINA       UNI0001      28-08-2020 12:19:42  28-08-2020 12:20:40
  EM0003         1113      LISA       UNI0002      28-08-2020 12:19:22  28-08-2020 12:22:22
  EM0004         1114      LISA       UNI0002      28-08-2020 20:00:09  28-08-2020 20:11:09 
  EM0004         1115      RYAN       UNI0003      29-08-2020 12:00:05  29-08-2020 12:02:05
```

So, based on my result and expectation there is still missing 1 filtering.
In this condition c.CREATED_DATE > a.CREATED_DATE, if  a.CREATED_DATE that smaller then c.CREATED_DATE is more than 1. the data show 2 row, it should be just one, get latest a.CREATED_DATE.
If i using ROW_NUMBER in logic it will be disturb row EM0003 & 1113 and EM0004 & 1114.

based on my current result, i want to grouping the transaction_id get based on latest REFERRAL_DATE, is it possible ?

Thank you so much for help I really appreciate it

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use explicit, modern, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Do you want the latest record from referral table ? or I didn't get it.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 there is 2 condition
1. Lastest record form referral if there is 2 referral code in 1 user name then connected to checkout table.
2. Need to check checkout table in column created_date, how many check out data in 1 user name, and is there any checkout data before 2nd referral code. If yes. connect first the first referral code to first checkout, and 2nd referral to next checkout.

Comment: @Diana: thanks for the clarification but with this logic how `EM0003` connected to  `1113` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Ok, So The user with name is Lisa unique code is UNI0002 has been have referral code EM0003 at 28-08-2020 12:19:22 (on TBL_REFERRAL). And then she made her first transaction on 28-08-2020 12:22:22 (onTBL_CHECKOUT connected with unique_code). And then she got 2nd referral code on 28-08-2020 20:00:09, That's mean the 2nd referral code is coming after her first transaction. So, her first transaction is should be connect with first referral which is EM0003 to 1113. This case is condition number 2 that i mention before.

Comment: @GordonLinoff like what i mention in the description. Because of process in the front end side there is some condition that make me can't give relation, between referral table and checkout table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` among those three tables, and `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function is need to filter out the records among latest `CHECKOUT_DATE` values :

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT r.REFERRAL_CODE, r.USER_NAME, u.UNIQUE_CODE, c.TRANS_ID, 
       r.CREATED_DATE AS "REFERRAL_DATE", c.CREATED_DATE AS "CHECKOUT_DATE",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.USER_NAME ORDER BY c.CREATED_DATE DESC) AS rn
  FROM TBL_CHECKOUT c
  LEFT JOIN TBL_USER u
    ON u.UNIQUE_CODE = c.UNIQUE_CODE 
  LEFT JOIN TBL_REFERRAL r
    ON r.USER_NAME = u.USER_NAME
 WHERE r.CREATED_DATE < c.CREATED_DATE
 )
 SELECT REFERRAL_CODE, USER_NAME, UNIQUE_CODE,TRANS_ID,REFERRAL_DATE,CHECKOUT_DATE
   FROM t
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Ok, so i actually have been tried your last query before, without ROW_NUMBER(). it has been come near to the expected result just need 1 more filter. i just need to grouping the trans id and get based on latest created_date on referral table. i am still try how to adding those filter

I also have been tried your query with adding ROW_NUMBER. But, still confusing why the result isn't show all data. I am still checking

Comment: This is work, just missing on ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION should be BY USER_NAME not employee code. Here is the final :

<WITH t AS
(
SELECT r.REFERRAL_CODE, r.USER_NAME, u.UNIQUE_CODE, c.TRANS_ID, 
       r.CREATED_DATE AS "REFERRAL_DATE", c.CREATED_DATE AS "CHECKOUT_DATE",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.USER_NAME ORDER BY c.CREATED_DATE DESC) AS rn
  FROM TBL_CHECKOUT c
  LEFT JOIN TBL_USER u
    ON u.UNIQUE_CODE = c.UNIQUE_CODE 
  LEFT JOIN TBL_REFERRAL r
    ON r.USER_NAME = u.USER_NAME
.....>